# Define different timeseries for different columns

Tags: r, datetime, time-series, forecasting

I have a dataframe where some of the columns are starting later than the other. Please find a reproducible example.

```
set.seed(354)
df <- data.frame(Product_Id = rep(1:100, each = 50), 
                     Date = seq(from = as.Date("2014/1/1"), 
                                to = as.Date("2018/2/1"), 
                                by = "month"), 
                     Sales = rnorm(100, mean = 50, sd= 20))
df <- df[-c(251:256, 301:312, 2551:2562, 2651:2662, 2751:2762), ]

library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(df, index = "Date", split = "Product_Id", FUN = as.yearmon)
tt <- as.ts(z)
```

Now for this dataframe for the columns 6,7,52,54 and 56 I want to define them as timeseries starting from a different date as compared to the rest of the dataframe. Supposedly the data begins from Jan 2000, column 6 will begin from July 2000, column 7 from Jan 2001 and so on. How should I proceed to do this?

Later, I want to perform a forecast on this dataset. Any inputs on this? Should I consider each column as a seperate dataframe and do the forecasting. Or can I convert each column to a different timeseries object that starts from the first non NA value?

Answer (score 0):

> Now for this dataframe for the columns 6,7,52,54 and 56 I want to define them as timeseries starting from a different date as compared to the rest of the dataframe. Supposedly the data begins from Jan 2000, column 6 will begin from July 2000, column 7 from Jan 2001 and so on. How should I proceed to do this?

There, AFAIK, no way to do this in R in a time series matrix. And if each column *started* at a different date, then (since each column has the same number of entries), each column would also need to *end* at a different date. Is this really what you need? A collection of time series that all happen to be of the same length (so they can fit into a matrix), but that start and end with offsets? I struggle to understand where something like this would be useful, outside a kind of forecasting competition.

If you really need this, then I would recommend you put your time series into a list structure. Then each one can start and end at any date, and they can be the same or different lengths. Take inspiration from `Mcomp::M3`.

> Later, I want to perform a forecast on this dataset. Any inputs on this? Should I consider each column as a seperate dataframe and do the forecasting. Or can I convert each column to a different timeseries object that starts from the first non NA value?

Since your `tt` is already a time series object, the simplest way would be simply to iterate over its columns:

```
fcst <- matrix(nrow=10,ncol=ncol(tt))
for ( ii in 1:ncol(tt) ) fcst <- forecast(ets(tt[,ii]),10)$mean
```

Note that most modeling functions in `forecast` will throw a warning and do something reasonable on encountering `NA` values. Here, e.g.:

```
1: In ets(tt[, ii]) :
  Missing values encountered. Using longest contiguous portion of time series
```

Of course, you could do something yourself inside the loop, e.g., search for the last `NA` and start the time series for modeling right after that (but make sure you fail gracefully if the last entry is `NA`).

Comment: Thankyou for the explanation. I, however, just figured out that using na.trim() function helps in completely ignoring the NAs and starting the analysis from the first non NA value. In my case it helps, as I only have NA in the beginning and also, they are just to show that the product was not exsistent in these months. I am using a combination of models to forecast and this seems to work just fine.